# Does the leader get to look at the Plot cards before distribution?

Tags: the-resistance

When playing The Resistance with the Plot Thickens expansion, the leader gets to distribute the Plot cards to other players of her choosing.  Is this a blind draw, or does the leader get to look at the cards before giving them to other players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the leader not only *looks* at the plot cards, he also *chooses* what card to give which player.

I couldn't find a copy of the original rules online, but [here](http://desktopgames.com.ua/games/642/resistance_rules_en.pdf) is a summary of the rules. Also note the plot cards are public information once dealt to a player.

Comment: Yes the leader gets to look at the card and then decide who gets it which is good for the leader if they are a spy.

Comment: It's good for the leader if the leader is resistance, too. In fact distributing the cards blind would favor spies.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does the leader get to look at the plot cards, but *everyone* does, and they can see who he distributes them to.